# Nested forms breaks outer form submit button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have two HTML forms, a fairly long one (user submitting details of a product they're ordering) inside of which there is a brief secondary form (where user can input + apply a discount code via AJAX). However, including the inner form -- which has proper opening and closing brackets -- seems to break the submit button for the outer form (Doesn't produce a javascript error, just does nothing when clicking on it).

Why might this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: If it helps, the inner form submit button is of type "submit," whereas the enclosing form's button is actually of type "image"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to wrap the inner "form" in a form tag, if that's what you're doing. The solution is just to bind the submit button for the discount code to a JavaScript function that runs your AJAX, i.e.

HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Discount Code" name="discountCode">
<a href="javascript:applyDiscount()" class="btn btn-primary">Apply</a>
```

Javascript

```
function applyDiscount() {
     discountCode = $('input[name="discountCode"]').val();
     $.ajax(...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Guess having 2 form tags conflicts?

Comment: @AaronMarks Yes, some browsers especially really don't like it when you have forms nested inside of forms and/or multiple `submit` inputs.  The easiest workaround is to use JS to execute the inner forms like this answer describes!

Comment: @AaronMarks If you check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form then you will see that a form element CANNOT contain another form element as per the HTML5 (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element) or HTML4 (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) standards. There is of course nothing stopping you having adjacent forms and using CSS or JavaScript to visually position one within another.